# aggregation with most recent records in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I was trying to do a simple data aggregation but I don't know how to count only those with latest timestamps.

The data I have looks like:

```
{'type': 'AAA', 'timestamp': '2016-03-12'} <- latest
{'type': 'AAA', 'timestamp': '2016-03-12'} <- latest
{'type': 'AAA', 'timestamp': '2015-03-12'}
{'type': 'BBB', 'timestamp': '2016-03-12'} <- latest
{'type': 'BBB', 'timestamp': '2015-03-12'}
{'type': 'BBB', 'timestamp': '2016-03-12'} <- latest
{'type': 'AAA', 'timestamp': '2015-03-12'}
{'type': 'CCC', 'timestamp': '2016-03-12'} <- latest
```

Say I'm interested in the number of each type, but only those most recently added records. Expected output is like.

```
AAA: 2
BBB: 2
CCC: 1
```

Here `timestamp` is a `date` type in elasticsearch.
Could anyone help with this?

Comment: Use date range aggregation. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html

Comment: yeah use date range aggregation, you will need to quantify latest in terms of if you are looking for current year, last year

Comment: Thanks guys. But what I'm looking for is dynamically find the latest record - What if I don't know what range to apply? Is there a way like `MAX(timestamp)`?